# How to find out the amount of preferred stock of Coca Cola Company?

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation, preferred-stocks, homework

I am having trouble finding out how many shares of preferred stock of Coca Cola Company are there. Is this information public? How to find the value of preferred stock? Is it the same as the value of common stock?

Answer (score 5):

Coca Cola doesn't seem to have any preferred shares outstanding. From the annual report, it does say that the number of common shares outstanding was 2,294,316,831 as of February 22, 2011. (cover page, right before the horizontal break)

But normally, you can find it either toward the beginning of the document or in the statement of shareholder's equity.

Comment: That's correct. The revised articles of incorporation (and original ones) give authority to issue shares of preferred stock, but there haven't been any outstanding for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this in the [annual report](http://ir.thecoca-colacompany.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=94566&p=irol-SECText&TEXT=aHR0cDovL2lyLmludC53ZXN0bGF3YnVzaW5lc3MuY29tL2RvY3VtZW50L3YxLzAwMDEwNDc0NjktMTEtMDAxNTA2L3htbA==). Preferred value is not the same as common value.

Comment: Thank you. I went through it, but I have not found either the number of preferred stock, nor their value... could you point me to the part of the report, where I can find the actual values?

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

From The Coca-Cola Company website, section for **[Investors: Stock History, Issues](http://www.thecoca-colacompany.com/investors/stockhistory.html)**

> Year
>    **1919**
>   `Original issue -- 600,000 shares`
>                `100,000 preferred`, par $100 each
>                `500,000 common`, without nominal or par value
>
> **1926**
>     `Eliminated 100,000 preferred` in November.

This means there were preferred shares issued in 1919. However, all preferred shares were "eliminated" (not sure what that means) as of 1926. There has been no subsequent reissuance of preferred shares of Coca-Cola since then. I think the company is still authorized to issue them, should they choose to do so in the future.

Answer (score -2):

They were issued in 1919 and eliminated in 1926. This means that Coca-Cola redeemed them in 1926 and either converted the preferred's to common stock or paid the preferred investor's back their full par value and took them off the books.

Comment: Welcome, again, to Money.SE. Mods see alerts for "new answers to old questions" and this one pinged us. How does your answer help the OP, as compared to Ellie's answer from Dec 24 '11? It looks like you summarized her answer. In general, it's wise to read the existing answers, and only respond if you are able to provide additional details.

Comment: This does expand on her answer. She said she didn't know what eliminated meant which I clarified.

Comment: That sort of minor clarification is better presented in a comment or edit on the original answer than in an entirely new answer.